# angular unit test - no provider for parent component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm creating my own [angular bootstrap library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap), and at the moment I'm stuck writing my unit tests for the navbar.

I've distilled [the troubled unit test down to the bare essentials](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/DO_NOT_MERGE-Breakdown-to-di-issue) and below is the summary:

## Unit test

```
describe('BsNavbarDropdownComponent', () => {
  let component: BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      declarations: [
        // Component to test
        BsNavbarDropdownComponent,

        // Mock components
        BsNavbarItemMockComponent,

        // Testbench
        BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: BsNavbarItemComponent, useClass: BsNavbarItemMockComponent }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-test',
  template: `
    <bs-navbar-item>
      <a [routerLink]='[]'>dropdown</a>
      <bs-navbar-dropdown>
        <bs-navbar-item>
          <a [routerLink]='["/b", "c"]'>bc</a>
        </bs-navbar-item>
      </bs-navbar-dropdown>
    </bs-navbar-item>`
})
class BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-item',
  template: `
  <li>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </li>`
})
class BsNavbarItemMockComponent {
}
```

## Unit-to-test

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './navbar-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class BsNavbarDropdownComponent {

  constructor(
    @Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => BsNavbarItemComponent)) navbarItem: BsNavbarItemComponent
  ) {
    this.navbarItem = navbarItem;
  }

  navbarItem: BsNavbarItemComponent;

}
```

In the `BsNavbarDropdownTestComponent` it's blindly obvious that the `bs-navbar-dropdown` (`BsNavbarDropdownComponent`) has a parent tag `bs-navbar-item` (`BsNavbarItemMockComponent`). In the unit-to-test I'm injecting the `BsNavbarItemComponent`, which is in the testing module provided as `BsNavbarItemMockComponent`.

However it seems like the unit test is still not succeeding.

```
npm run nx run-many -- --target=test --projects=ng-bootstrap-demo --with-deps  --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

Result:

```
 FAIL   xxx-ng-bootstrap  libs/xxx-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/navbar/navbar-dropdown/navbar-dropdown.component.spec.ts
  ● BsNavbarDropdownComponent › should create

    NG0201: No provider for BsNavbarItemComponent found in NodeInjector. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0201
```

Again, note that the module has the following providers:

```
providers: [
  { provide: BsNavbarItemComponent, useClass: BsNavbarItemMockComponent }
]
```

So what's wrong with this? Why is the `BsNavbarItemComponent` provider not found in the unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module provider is not being injected because of `@Host` annotation on the injection.

so your mock component should be injectable by the original component token

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-item',
  template: `
  <li>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </li>`,
  providers: [provide: BsNavbarItemComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => BsNavbarItemMockComponent)]
})
class BsNavbarItemMockComponent {
}
```